# Replacing year with English words in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, qdap

I need to pre-process a speech transcript for forced-alignment. However, I am having difficulty with replacing year with text representation. For example, 1984 needs to be replaced with "nineteen eighty four". I tried the replace_number function of the qdap package. The package is awesome, but it replaces 1984 with "one thousand nine hundred eighty four" instead. Are there other functions from any R packages that may I try? Thanks!

Comment: english package by Bill Venables

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: also check out https://github.com/coolbutuseless/numberwang 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can split each into two parts and separately convert each part to a character representation:

```
year = 1984
paste(
    replace_number(substr(as.character(year), 1, 2),
    replace_number(substr(as.character(year), 3, 4)
)
```

this would yield `nineteen eightyfour`

Comment: But how about the case of 1903? How do I make it "nineteen oh three"?

Comment: you could just add some special logic for the first decade of each century.

Comment: Thank you! This is clever!